# Why does the error "file.too.large" is not being showed (correctly) in the jsp?

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2, validation

I have an application that let you upload some photos. I have a jsp page with a form to select what photo you want to upload:

**subir-foto.jsp**

```
...
<s:form action="SubirFoto" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" theme="bootstrap">
   <s:file name="foto" label="Foto" />
   <s:submit value="Upload" align="center" />
</s:form>
...
```

I want that with this form, the user can only upload certain type of files (like jpg, gif ...) and don't let the user to upload photos with a size bigger than 2 MB.

**struts.xml**

```
<action
        name="SubirFoto"
        class="impl.redex.presentation.profile.upload.SubirFotosAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>
            <param name="allowedTypes">
                image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
            </param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="dentroStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsps/foto/foto-subida.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsps/foto/subir-foto.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The file uploading works perfectly except one thing. I can upload any photo if it satisfies the requirements asked. If I try to upload a file that is not a photo (for example, a plain text file), the application puts me the error that I have defined in `global.properties` in the input of the form of the jsp.

**global.properties**

```
struts.messages.error.uploading - No se ha podido subir el fichero
struts.messages.error.file.too.large - El fichero es demasiado grande. El tamaño máximo es de 2MB.
struts.messages.error.content.type.not.allowed - Tipo de fichero no aceptado. Sólo es válido si la foto \
está en formato jpg/jpeg, gif o png.
```

The problem comes if I try to upload an image bigger than 2 MB, the application redirects me to **subir-foto.jsp** but it doesn't put any error in the jsp page.

I have experimented a bit and if I put `<s:actionerror />` in subir-foto.jsp an when I upload the big photo it appear this:

```
the request was rejected because its size (17224595) exceeds the configured maximum (2097152)
```

As you can see, this is not the error that I have defined in `global.properties`.

Why are not this two different errors field errors? Is this a problem with bootstrap plugin? Or is it a bug of Struts2? Am I doing something wrong? Any help with be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is global.properties registered as a custom i18n resource? e.g., is this in your struts.xml (or struts.properties): `<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global"/>`?

Comment: Yes, I have in my struts.xml the line `<constant
  name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
  value="global" />`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I search more in Google and I found a blog that explain the error (the blog entry is from 2008 and I'm using Struts 2.3.4):

http://blog.bielu.com/2008/09/solution-to-struts2-upload-file-error.html

I summarize how I solve my problem. The problem was that the message `the request was rejected because its size ...` is hardcoded in one of the Struts2 classes.

> There are at least three solutions to this problem (all of them are pain in the ass): one is to reimplement `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest` class; second one is to reimplement `org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor` class.

The third one is put a `validate`  method in the FileUpload class.

```
@Override
public void validate() {
    boolean error = false;

    Collection<?> tmp = getActionErrors();

    for (Object o : tmp) {
        if (o.toString().contains(
                "the request was rejected because its size")) {

            if (!error) {
                addFieldError("foto",
                        "El tamaño de la foto es muy grande (Máximo: 2MB)");
                error = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Anyway, I still can't understand why the message that I defined wasn't working because in all sites that I search told me to overwrite the `struts.messages.error.file.too.large` or why were both errors different type of errors (field and action errors).

Thanks to everybody for your time.

Comment: +1 Nice find. None of the solutions are particularly good. The approach of passing the exception message through as an action error is going to cause internationalization issues.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, This error comes into picture if you are trying to upload a file more than the file size you specified for struts.multipart.maxSize

There's a pretty easy solution:
In your struts.xml, increase the file size value of struts.multipart.maxSize,

```
  <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="50777216000" />
  <param name="maximumSize">15728640</param>
```

Keep param name="maximumSize" value **less than**  struts.multipart.maxSize value,
As in above case, you will get your customised  error defined in global.properties unless you exceed struts.multipart.maxSize limit..so try to keep struts.multipart.maxSize value to some high range.